# Equivalent formulations of Furstenberg x2 x3 conjecture

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Define $T_p: \mathbb{T}\longrightarrow\mathbb{T}$ to be $T_p(x)=px \ mod\mathbb{Z}$, 
Furstenberg x2 x3 conjecture is as follows:

> The unique non-atomic (ergodic) borel measure on $\mathbb{T}$ that is $T_2$ and $T_3$ invariant is Lebesgue measure.

In some sources I saw the measure was required to be ergodic while in others ergodicity was omitted. In this [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44234/furstenbergs-conjecture-on-2-3-invariant-continuous-probability-measures-on-the) question ergodicity is omitted and it is argued in the comments that the two formulations are equivalent but I couldn't understand why. To be precise, my question is why Furstenberg "ergodic" conjecture implies Furstenberg "non-ergodic" conjecture, or in what sense these conjectures are equivalent.

Comment: I'm confused as well. It seems Andreas first argues the equivalence assuming another conjecture, and then, in his last comment, says the two conjecture are (unconditionally) equivalent. Do you, at least, understand his first comment, explaining the conditional equivalence?

Comment: I understand it, but as you said his second (upvoted) comment is confusing. After reading it I thought that by "are conjectured to be" he might have referred to Furstenberg conjecture itself